# DNN 9.1.1 gives 302 headers on multiple DNN files when not logged in

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

DNN 9.1.1 gives 302 headers on multiple DNN files when not logged in (see screenshot Fiddler). The result is a very ugly page with no css and javascript.

No error logs.

The website shows all files after I have logged in. What can this be?

- local site
- DNN 9.1.1
- Windows 10
- MS SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)

I gave the .Net user (NETWORK SERVICE), thats uses the app pool IIS, full control

[image: Testing with Fiddler]

Comment: Do you have any extra site aliases setup?

Comment: Yes... Why @notandy?